# Why doesn't my new cygwin .bashrc interactive check work?

Tags: bash, ssh, cygwin, sshd

I just updated Cygwin and the new `.bashrc` contains this line right at the top:

```
echo "BEFORE TEST"
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return
echo "AFTER TEST"
```

I understand if not running interactive, you don't need to do anything, but my problem is that if I `ssh` with a command:

```
ssh localhost pwd
```

I see this:

```
BEFORE TEST
```

So, obviously, it fails the `[[ "$-" != *i* ]]` test and returns. Obviously `ssh localhost pwd` is a trivial example, but I expect `.bashrc` to be run all the way through if running a command through `ssh`. My actual automation runs commands remotely against this cygwin instance and is failing because the path (which is set by my `.bashrc`) is not getting set correctly.

Furthermore, can anyone explain what that test is actually doing? What is `i`? What is `$-` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run a single command (`pwd` in your case) through `ssh`, it is not an interactive shell, so the behavior is correct, in my opinion.

You should set your `PATH` in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, not in `~/.bashrc`.

As found in [`bash(1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+testing+%28wheezy%29&format=html&locale=en) man page:

```
   PARAMETERS
      (...)
      Special Parameters
          The shell treats several parameters specially.   These  parameters  may
          only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
          (...)
          -      Expands  to  the  current option flags as specified upon invoca-
                 tion, by the set builtin command, or  those  set  by  the  shell
                 itself (such as the -i option).
```

So `i` contained in `$-` means that the `-i` option has been used (or automatically set by the shell, being interactive).

Answer (score 2):

[enzotib’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31295/22812) is correct (so upvoted) but I thought I’d complement it with details relating to shell start-up when the shell is launched via SSH.

Readers of Bash’s documentation might be wondering why there is need for `.bashrc` to check if it is running in an interactive shell given that a `.bashrc` is only sourced for *interactive* Bash shells.  Nevertheless, the default `~/.bashrc` included with most (if not all) Unix-like systems include some type of check (testing `$-` or `$PS1`) to ensure the current shell is interactive.

The reason for this is that **Bash has a special case for remote shells**.  While non-interactive Bash shells don’t normally run `~/.bashrc` commands at start-up, a special case is made when the shell is [Invoked by remote shell daemon](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
>   connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell
>   daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. If Bash
>   determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands
>   from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable. It will not do this if
>   invoked as `sh`.

For more information, see my answer to [Why does bashrc check whether the current shell is interactive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257571/22812).