# Why does bashrc check whether the current shell is interactive?

Tags: bash, interactive

On my Arch install, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/skel/.bashrc` contain these lines:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

On Debian, `/etc/bash.bashrc` has:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

And `/etc/skel/.bashrc`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

According to `man bash`, however, non-interactive shells don't even read these files:

> When `bash` is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Bash behaves as if the following commands were executed: `if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi` but the value of the `PATH` variable is not used to search for the filename.

If I understand correctly, the `*.bashrc` files will only be read if `BASH_ENV` is set to point to them. This is something that can't happen by chance and will only occur if someone has explicitly set the variable accordingly.

That seems to break the possibility of having scripts source a user's `.bashrc` automatically by setting `BASH_ENV`, something that could come in handy. Given that bash will never read these files when run non-interactively unless explicitly told to do so, why do the default `*bashrc` files disallow it?

Comment: For a practical answer, see [SCP fails without error](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error/18647#18647)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This is a question that I was going to post here a few weeks ago. Like *terdon*, I understood that a `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive Bash shells so there should be no need for `.bashrc` to check if it is running in an interactive shell. Confusingly, **all** the distributions I use (Ubuntu, RHEL and Cygwin) had some type of check (testing `$-` or `$PS1`) to ensure the current shell is interactive.  I don’t like [cargo cult programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/cargo-cult-programming.html) so I set about understanding the purpose of this code in my `.bashrc`.

### Bash has a special case for remote shells

After researching the issue, I discovered that *remote shells* are treated differently. While non-interactive Bash shells don’t normally run `~/.bashrc` commands at start-up, a special case is made when the shell is [Invoked by remote shell daemon](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
>   connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell
>   daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. If Bash
>   determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands
>   from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable. It will not do this if
>   invoked as `sh`.  The `--norc` option may be used to inhibit this behavior,
>   and the `--rcfile` option may be used to force another file to be read, but
>   neither `rshd` nor `sshd` generally invoke the shell with those options or
>   allow them to be specified.

#### Example

Insert the following at the start of a remote `.bashrc`. (If `.bashrc` is sourced by `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, temporarily disable this while testing):

```
echo bashrc
fun()
{
    echo functions work
}
```

Run the following commands locally:

```
$ ssh remote_host 'echo $- $0'
bashrc
hBc bash
```

- No `i` in `$-` indicates that the shell is *non-interactive*.
- No leading `-` in `$0` indicates that the shell is not a *login shell*.

Shell functions defined in the remote `.bashrc` can also be run:

```
$ ssh remote_host fun
bashrc
functions work
```

I noticed that the `~/.bashrc` is *only* sourced when a command is specified as the argument for `ssh`. This makes sense: when `ssh` is used to start a regular login shell, `.profile` or `.bash_profile` are run (and `.bashrc` is only sourced if explicitly done so by one of these files).

The main benefit I can see to having `.bashrc` sourced when running a (non-interactive) remote command is that shell functions can be run. However, most of the commands in a typical `.bashrc` are only relevant in an interactive shell, e.g., aliases aren’t expanded unless the shell is interactive.

### Remote file transfers can fail

This isn’t usually a problem when `rsh` or `ssh` are used to start an interactive login shell or when non-interactive shells are used to run commands. However, it *can be a problem* for programs such as `rcp`, `scp` and `sftp` that use *remote shells* for transferring data.

It turns out that the remote user’s default shell (like Bash) is implicitly started when using the `scp` command. There’s no mention of this in the man page – only a mention that `scp` uses `ssh` for its data transfer.  This has the consequence that **if the `.bashrc` contains any commands that print to standard output, file transfers will fail**, e.g, 
[scp fails without error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18231/scp-fails-without-error/18647#18647).

See also this related Red Hat bug report from 15 years ago, [scp breaks when there's an echo command in /etc/bashrc](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527) (which was eventually closed as `WONTFIX`).

### Why `scp` and `sftp` fail

[SCP (Secure copy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) and [SFTP (Secure File Transfer Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) have their own protocols for the local and remote ends to exchange information about the file(s) being transferred. Any unexpected text from the remote end is (wrongly) interpreted as part of the protocol and the transfer fails.  According to a [FAQ from the Snail Book](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/sftp-corruption.auto.html)

> What often happens, though, is that there are statements in either the
>   system or per-user shell startup files on the server (`.bashrc`, `.profile`,
>   `/etc/csh.cshrc`, `.login`, etc.) which output text messages on login,
>   intended to be read by humans (like `fortune`, `echo "Hi there!"`, etc.).
>
> Such code should only produce output on interactive logins, when there is a
>   `tty` attached to standard input. If it does not make this test, it will
>   insert these text messages where they don't belong: in this case, polluting
>   the protocol stream between `scp2`/`sftp` and `sftp-server`.
>
> The reason the shell startup files are relevant at all, is that **`sshd`
>   employs the user's shell when starting any programs on the user's behalf**
>   (using e.g.  /bin/sh -c "command"). This is a Unix tradition, and has
>   advantages:
>
> - The user's usual setup (command aliases, environment variables, umask,
>     etc.) are in effect when remote commands are run.
> - The common practice of setting an account's shell to /bin/false to disable
>     it will prevent the owner from running any commands, should authentication
>     still accidentally succeed for some reason.

#### SCP protocol details

For those interested in the details of how SCP works, I found interesting information in [How the SCP protocol works](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works) which includes details on **Running scp with talkative shell profiles on the remote side?**:

> For example, this can happen if you add this to your shell profile on the
>   remote system:
>
> echo ""
>
> Why it just hangs? That comes from the way how `scp` in **source** mode
>   waits for the confirmation of the first protocol message. If it's not binary
>   0, it expects that it's a notification of a remote problem and waits for
>   more characters to form an error message until the new line arrives. Since
>   you didn't print another new line after the first one, your local `scp` just
>   stays in a loop, blocked on `read(2)`. In the meantime, after the shell
>   profile was processed on the remote side, `scp` in sink mode was started,
>   which also blocks on `read(2)`, waiting for a binary zero denoting the start
>   of the data transfer.

## Conclusion / TLDR

Most of the statements in a typical `.bashrc` are only useful for an interactive shell – not when running remote commands with `rsh` or `ssh`. In most such situations, setting shell variables, aliases and defining functions isn’t desired – and printing *any text* to standard out is actively harmful if transferring files using programs such as `scp` or `sftp`. Exiting after verifying that the current shell is non-interactive is the safest behaviour for `.bashrc`.

Comment: nice article. but I should do with that? i do have check in by .bashrc but still scp exit with 0 code and do not copy anything to remote box

Comment: @ses It'd be best to ask a new question where you can describe your situation in greater detail.

Comment: Slight nitpick re. "No leading - in $0 indicates that the shell is not a login shell." Bash may also consider itself a login shell if --login is passed; `shopt -q login_shell` is the right way to check for a login shell.

Comment: I would like to know if other shells, i.e. `zsh` behave the same. I mean, will `.zshrc` be consumed when running a remote comman?

Answer (score 19):

The man page neglects to mention that `bash` also sources `.bashrc` for non-interactive remote shells, as in

```
ssh hostname command
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n1010

```
 COMMAND        EXECUTE BASHRC
 --------------------------------
 bash -c foo        NO
 bash foo           NO
 foo                NO
 rsh machine ls     YES (for rsh, which calls 'bash -c')
 rsh machine foo    YES (for shell started by rsh) NO (for foo!)
 echo ls | bash     NO
 login              NO
 bash               YES
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n1050

```
          /* If we were run by sshd or we think we were run by rshd, execute
             ~/.bashrc if we are a top-level shell. */
          if ((run_by_ssh || isnetconn (fileno (stdin))) && shell_level < 2)
            {
              maybe_execute_file (SYS_BASHRC, 1);
              maybe_execute_file (bashrc_file, 1);
```

Comment: Do you source your .bashrc from your .bash_profile (or .profile)?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point.  An empty `.bash_profile` would exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Not sure what that's showing me. Are you saying that `rsh` (which I've never used) sources `~/.bashrc`? And that, by extension, Linux distros block it for `bash` just in case anyone ever tries to run a script with `rsh`? `ssh server` shouldn't touch `.bashrc` since that's a login shell anyway. Not unless your system is one of those that sources ~/.bashrc` from `~/.profile`. And `ssh server command` shouldn't even do that. Certainly doesn't on my system.

Comment: No.  I linked you to the `bash` source, not the `rsh` source. :)  The comment applies to `ssh` as well, it was just written a very long time ago.   See updated answer with more source.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful, thank you. How would I test this though? I tried adding an `echo` at the very top of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` (before the interactive shell tests) and then ssh into the target machine with `ssh server hostname` and while `hostname` was run, I didn't see either of my echoes. Is it that my `shell_level` (whatever that is) is not `<2`?

Comment: @terdon That's cool. I don't suppose you're login shell is set to `/bin/sh`? That would prevent `.bashrc` from being sourced when running `ssh` commands (even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash`).

Answer (score 6):

By convention, `.bashrc` is place where user store the customize configuration for the shell.

These customize configuration can be environment variables, aliases, fancy prompt. With a non-interactive shell, those short of things are meaningless. Moreover, a non-interactive shell can be call in many contexts, you're not sure those environment variables can lead to false negative case, or even security vulnerable.

A closest example is an alias like:

```
alias cp='cp -i'
```

Then it hang your non-interactive shell forever.

So the check perform at the top of `.bashrc` to ensure that we won't get trouble.

---

Because the shell can be called as non-interactive *login* shell, so explicitly block sourcing `*bashrc` make no sense.

When the shell was [called as non-interactive login shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoked-as-an-interactive-login-shell_002c-or-with-_002d_002dlogin), it source `/etc/profile`, then source the first one found in `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, **or as a 
>   non-interactive  shell with the --login option**, it first reads
>   and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists.   After  reading    that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,    in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one  that    exists  and  is 
>   readable.

Nothing prevent those files from sourcing `.bashrc` itself, so doing the check inside `.bashrc` is safer and make things simple.

Comment: Yes, I know that. This is why non-interactive shells don't source `*bashrc` files at all. My question is why do various Linux vendors go to the trouble of explicitly blocking non-interactive shells from reading these files if these files aren't read by non-interactive shells anyway.

Comment: @terdon: Because a shell can be called as non-interactive *login* shell, then a login shell will source `.bash_profile`, which can be source `.bashrc`.

Comment: No, in non-interactive shells, the only thing that's read is `$BASH_ENV`. Both `*profile` and `*bashrc` are ignored. Or, at least, that's what the man page says. However, as Mikel has shown the man page might be lying.

Comment: @terdon: Read my updated answer with the link in it. Have you try `bash -l -c :` to invoke a non-interactive login shell?

Comment: Wow. You're absolutely right. I've read that part about `--login` 100 times but, apparently, it had never registered. Thanks!

Comment: Also non-interactive login shell is easy to get with ssh.

Comment: @Joshua but that doesn't seem to read bashrc. That's precisely what had confused me.