# Can Bash tell an interactive SSH session from an in-line SSH session?

Tags: bash, shell, login, prompt

I have a Bash script that needs to be run from an interactive prompt, due to environment variables and configuration that only seems to be read when actually logged into a session. Examples below:

**Good**

```
me@client:~$ ssh box
user@box:~$ /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

**Bad**

```
me@client:~$ ssh box "/usr/local/bin/myscript"
```

Is there any Bash-fu that I can use in my script to determine if it's being run via a one-line SSH command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check whether there is a terminal connected to standard input (that's what the `tty` command does). Add these lines to your script:

```
if ! tty >/dev/null; then
    echo "Must be run from a tty"
    exit 1
fi
```

Your script will now exit with an error unless run correctly:

```
$ ssh badabing ~/scripts/a.sh
Must be run from a tty

$ ssh badabing
terdon@badabing ~ $ ~/scripts/a.sh
Works!
```

Comment: In this case, OP's script probably wants `~/.profile` etc. to be read.

Comment: @muru yes, I know, and had even written a first draft of this answer suggesting they just add `. ~/.profile` to the script, but that could cause other problems. For example, what if `~/.profile` sources `.bashrc` and `.bashrc` sources a third file that sets up the environment? In that case, assuming the `.bashrc` is [exiting on non-interactive shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257571/22222), the same problem would occur. It's probably worth posting an answer suggesting the OP source whatever files are necessary but I felt this was both cleaner and actually answers the question asked.