# Pass ssh remote command from bash to zsh

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, putty

I am running a remote putty session from windows to my Red Hat Enterprise Linux server.

Due to company restrictions, I am unable to change my Linux user's default shell from bash to zsh. I instead have read only access to `~./bash_profile`, which executes `~/.bashrc` (where I also have only read only access), which in turn executes `~/.bash_custom` where I have write access. Inside `~/.bash_custom`, I execute zsh to change my shell.

Including the line to execute zsh prevents the execution of any remote command provided by putty. I know this is the problem since if I comment out my execution of zsh it works fine.

I have several aliases and PATH modifications inside my zsh which I'd like to use as part of the remote command executed from putty. How can I pass the remote command from the bash shell to zsh for it to be executed there?

Comment: What Linux are you using? Sounds like it is one of the ones that have `.profile` source `.bashrc` because normally, `.bashrc` wouldn't even be read when sshing into a machine. Do you have code in your `~/.profile` that makes it source `.bashrc`? Also, are you opening an interactive shell session or are you just trying to run a single command?

Comment: @terdon [Bash reads `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257571/why-does-bashrc-check-whether-the-current-shell-is-interactive/257613#257613) when invoked **non**-interactively over rsh or ssh (with some variation between versions and distributions, IIRC making ssh like rsh was originally a Debian patch).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but this looks self-inflicted. Why would you `exec zsh` in `.bashrc`? I can't think of a good reason to do that. Why not do it in `.bash_profile`, so that it's only done in interactive shells?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' yes, non interactively only, that's why I asked if the OP is opening an interactive session or trying to run a single command. If not, if this is opening an interactive login shell, then they must have a profile that reads bashrc.

Comment: @terdon I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I have read only access to `~/.bash_profile` which then executes `~/.bashrc` which I also have only read only access to which then executed `~/.bash_custom` which I have write access to and which is where I run zsh

Comment: Please add this to your question, it is very relevant. This is a non-standard setup. Sounds like you just need to wrap your `$HOME/bin/zsh` in code that makes sure it is only executed when running interactively.

Comment: Will do, but I'd like to preferably pass it to zsh instead because I have aliases and a different PATH in zsh that I'd like to use in my remote commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some (most these days) systems, `bash` is configured at build time so that when run over ssh, `bash` reads `~/.bashrc` (and corresponding system-wide file in `/etc`) even when run non-interactively like when running `ssh some command` where `sshd`  runs `bash -c 'some command'`¹.

What you could do is add at the top  of your `~/.bash_custom`:

```
export SHELL="$(command -v zsh)" # tell everyone your preferred shell
case ${SSH_CONNECTION+s}:${-//[^ilc]}:$#:$SHLVL in
  (s:c:0:1) exec zsh -c -- "$BASH_EXECUTION_STRING";;
  (*:i:0:*) exec zsh;;
esac
```

That executes `zsh` with the same code when bash is run as `bash -c 'some code'` by `sshd`, and `zsh` alone when bash is run interactively.

You could limit that second case to cases where bash is invoked as a login shell only with:

```
if shopt -q login_shell; then
  exec zsh
fi
```

and/or only via `ssh` by replacing `*:i:0:*` with `s:i:0:*`

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, it should run `bash -c -- 'some command'` but since there are shells where that's not supported (or not needed like in csh, fish, rc...), it doesn't.</sup>